# How do I install fontforge on Kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu, ppa, fonts

Very straightforward question. When I try and run the PPAs it tells me that there is no release and it won't do it for security reasons. Does it not exist?

When I go to their website, they offer the ability to compile from source but that's a whole lot of stuff to do, and I thought fontforge came standard on Ubuntu and stuff? Or at least I would expect it to be installable from a deb or something. Isn't Ubuntu like one of the biggest distros? So I would think that they would have a version of font forge for it by now... right?

Comment: Sorry I am new. Universe means it comes default with Ubuntu right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### fontforge PPA not available for 18.04

The PPA for fontforge is not available for 18.04 as you can see on the PPA's page: https://launchpad.net/~fontforge/+archive/ubuntu/fontforge.

First click `Technical details about this PPA` and then check the dropdown menu `Display sources.list entries for:`

### How to install fontforge in 18.04 (universe repo)

To install fontforge, which is availbe in the universe repository as dsstorefile pointed out in a comment:

Enable universe:

`sudo add-apt-repository universe`

See also: [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Then:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install fontforge`

### Remove the useless PPA from your system

Now it is a wise idea to remove the PPA from your system, as it has no use to you.

`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:fontforge/fontforge`

`sudo apt-get update`